# How can I perform connectionless ldap call using Java?

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

In order to work with AD's Global Catalog from a Java program , I am required to perform a CLDap (Connectionless ldap) call from my Java program.
I am looking for some open source to perform this task, but in vain.
Has someone experienced creating CLDAP connection in Java and can help around?

Many thanks
Zaske

Comment: I am confused by this question. LDAP is a TCP/IP protocol and requires a connection. Is the client attempting to connect to an LDAP server using UDP?

Comment: CLDAP is a different protocol - connectionless LDAP. I may have used a bad title, I apologize. Connectionless LDAP is based on UDP but uses LDAP PDUs (I hope I used the correct term) and is used to perform "ldap ping" against Active-Directory (for example).

Answer (score 0):

Surprising requirement. CLDAP was moved to 'historic status' in 2003, see [RFC 3352](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3352.txt). Based on that, (a) I doubt you will ever see a Java API for it, and (b) I would just use LDAP over TCP: it will work at least as well. See also [here](http://onemansjourneyintolinux.blogspot.com.au/2008/06/cldap.html) where its removal from OpenLDAP is discussed.

Comment: When you want to work with GLobal Catalog, it is still required to work with CLDAP - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247811 I know the article is for Windows 2000 server, but there are still enough organizations that need to use WIN2K servers.